# Authentication as two different users when connecting to IIS7

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7, windows-authentication

I apologize if I completely bungle this question and description.  I have a test and production asp.net application both using windows authentication.  They are the same build but for some reason, on my development machine, the test application has started authenticating me as domain\user1 while the production application authenticates me as domain\user2 who I am logged in as.  If I try a different machine, both the test and production applications authenticate me as domain\user2 as expected.  This happens in both IE and Firefox and only on my dev machine.  I've cleared my cache, checked everything I can think of to check and I'm probably missing something obvious.  Any thoughts as to why Firefox and IE would be passing me as domain\user1 to the test application?

Comment: Do you get an auth dialog in the browser(s) or are you automatically logged in?

Comment: I am automatically logged in.  I've gone in to the local intranet zone security settings and changed to "prompt for user name and password" and the windows security dialog shows me as the different user...though I can switch users and type the same user/pass as what I am logged in as and things work as expected.  I select "remember" and then change user authentication to "automatic logon only in Intranet Zone," reboot and this particular page keeps authenticating me as the other user (not the user I am logged in as).